# Conditional @if statement for preselected options in Laravel 5 form using Blade templates

Tags: forms, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In creating an update form using the same template as the create form, I wish to have the previously chosen options selected. Something like this makes sense, but Blade cannot parse it:

```
{!! Form::select('number', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] @if (!empty($at)), $at->id @endif) !!}
```

I use the `$at` variable to identify if I'm updating or creating a new entry.

I could write 2 separate statements and echo whichever one is relevant (or use a separate template, but I'm trying to keep the code DRY.

Comment: You don't necessarily *have* to use the `Form::` helper; you could always write a `<select name="number">...</select>` and encompass that with your `$at` logic. Honestly (and this is probably due to habit more than anything) I don't use `Form::` at all in my Laravel applications.

Comment: @TimLewis `Form::` is actually not even included in L5 core these days. That said, it comes with some handy functionality, like filling in old input when an error occurs. I wouldn't want to go back to manually doing all that. :-D

Comment: `<input type="text" name="example" value="{{ Input::old("example") ? Input::old("example"):"" }}"/>` That's not too bad is it? :P or in the case of a `<select>`: `<option value="1" {{ Input::old("example") == "1" ? "selected":"" }}>1</option>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside blade tags is just normal PHP. That also means you can use a shorthand inline if:

```
{!! Form::select('number', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (empty($at) ? null : $at->id)) !!}
```